# How can get the Tag's object from the ID number

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, tags

I would like to know if there is a way to get a tag of a canvas object from his ID.

I have working in a game what i needs to delete all itens with the same tag, but i just have one of ID's from those objects. Exemple:

```
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width = x, height = y)
collider_object = canvas.create_*(any)*(coordnates_x, coordinates_y)

for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        object_one = canvas.create_*(any)*(coordinates_x1, coordinates_y1, tag = '%i%i'%(i,j))
        object_two = canvas.create_*(any)*(coordinates_x2, coordinates_y2, tag = '%i%i'%(i,j))        
        object_three = canvas.create_*(any)*(coordinates_x3, coordinates_y3, tag = '%i%i'%(i,j))

ID = canvas.find_overlapping(object_collider*(coordinates)*)

canvas.delete(ID['tag'])

IDLE response: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

How you can see the objects have the same tag but diferent coordinates. what means that not necessarily they will colide at the same time with collider_object.

I need to get the tag from the ID number, so i would delete all objects when any of them with the same tag collided with collider_object.

Comment: The code you provided has syntax errors. Please provide valid code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `itemcget` method to get any configuration option for any canvas item.

```
tags = canvas.itemcget(ID, "tags")
```

Note: this will return a string rather than a list. Since your objects only have a single tag, that shouldn't be an issue.